# Does mining in a pool help the network?

Tags: mining, security, mining-theory

So basically, if you solo mine you create decentralization, but your chance to get reward is almost nonexistent.

When you mine with a pool, you don't validate anything. You just hash blocks produced by pool.

So the pool itself can perform an attack on the network, if it decides to.

Answer (score 1):

All mining helps the network so long as neither the miner (or pool if the miner is using one), is trying to perform an attack.

Comment: Yesss, but pool can try to perform an attack

Comment: Yes, as I stated. As can any miner with enough hashrate.